# Send Mail to Multiple Recipient Without Recipients seeing the other people i am sending it to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

I am trying to development this app that has a landing page where i can collect email addresses, log in as an admin and send mail to all the subscribed users, i am using Action mailer and my gmail account smtp configuration.

When i do send the mail, everyone gets cc'ed, and seeing as i am testing with my own google mail accounts, i can see the other people cc'ed.

Mailforsubcriber Controller

```
def create
@mailforsubscriber = Mailforsubscriber.new(mailforsubscriber_params)
respond_to do |format|
  if @mailforsubscriber.save
               RecipientMailer.newsletter(@mailforsubscriber).deliver_now

          format.html { redirect_to @mailforsubscriber, notice: 'Mail for subscriber was successfully sent.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @mailforsubscriber }

  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @mailforsubscriber.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

This is the recipient mailer code

```
 class RecipientMailer < ApplicationMailer
  require 'digest/sha2'
  default from: "notification@example.com"
  default to: Proc.new {Subscribeduser.pluck(:email) }
  default "Message-ID" => "#{Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(Time.now.to_i.to_s)}@domain.com"


  def newsletter(mailforsubscriber)
      @mailforsubscriber = mailforsubscriber
      mail(subject: "Newsletter")
  end

end
```

how do i get around this?.

Answer (score 2):

try use the CCO field, it's works like CC field, but don't show the other e-mails for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this in your action mailer,

```
def newsletter(mailforsubscriber)
  @mailforsubscriber = mailforsubscriber
  mail(:to => @mailforsubscriber.email, :subject => "Newsletter")
end
```

Here i have called the method send_mail_persons and passed the recipients info as a parameter.This logic will make you loop across all the email ids and then send individually. If you want to send mail to all the users at once then you can use **:bcc**, say

```
mail(:to => "@mailforsubscriber.email" ,  :subject => "Example Subject",
 :bcc => ["bcc1@abc.com", "bcc2@abc.com"])
```

If you are new to Rails, i would suggest to read this [Action Mailer Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html). This covers end to end flow of a basic mailer template integration from controller to view.

Comment: i am trying to send it to alot of people, without having to type their email addresses manually.  the "mailforsubscriber.email"  bit would mean that the mail for subscriber has an email address, which is not so. there is essentially no relationship between the mail for subscriber and the subscribed user in the models, as that could get complicated.

Comment: "i am trying to send it to a lot of people" - meaning the bcc bit of your proposed solution is not a good fit to my application. if i wasnt clear enough in the previous comment

Comment: You can pass array of email ids stored in the variable to action mailer. Since you want to send to multiple users in one call then use :to => [array of ids].  This will result in exposing all the mail ids to other too.

Comment: "This will result in exposing all the mail ids to other too", this is what i am trying to avoid..

Comment: Then you only have one solution to use Bcc if you want to execute in one call else loop around with individual email ids.